# MariaDB backups: meaning of backup and restore states returned by Cloud Foundry

Tags: swisscomdev

I did not find any documentation about the states of a MariaDB backup and the restore (https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide-sc/services/backups.html).

For example, when I make the API call `GET /custom/service_instances/{service-instance-id}/backups`, the following JSON is returned as a response. In the response there are the attributes "status" in the entity of a backup, and the entity of a restore.

```
{
   "total_results": 2,
   "total_pages": 1,
   "prev_url": null,
   "next_url": null,
   "resources": [
      {
         "metadata": {
            "guid": "95b9108a-1903-4cea-b52e-bbb3b0414986",
            "url": "/custom/service_instances/3955ad28-3f47-4f08-8eee-748f6e162d46/backups/95b9108a-1903-4cea-b52e-bbb3b0414986",
            "created_at": "2016-10-03T20:52:04Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-10-03T20:52:34Z"
         },
         "entity": {
            "service_instance_id": "3955ad28-3f47-4f08-8eee-748f6e162d46",
            "status": "CREATE_SUCCEEDED",
            "restores": []
         }
      },
      {
         "metadata": {
            "guid": "4ffff7d4-55a8-4e57-9035-98ed11380991",
            "url": "/custom/service_instances/3955ad28-3f47-4f08-8eee-748f6e162d46/backups/4ffff7d4-55a8-4e57-9035-98ed11380991",
            "created_at": "2016-10-03T08:50:07Z",
            "updated_at": "2016-10-03T08:50:37Z"
         },
         "entity": {
            "service_instance_id": "3955ad28-3f47-4f08-8eee-748f6e162d46",
            "status": "CREATE_SUCCEEDED",
            "restores": [
               {
                  "metadata": {
                     "guid": "1a33a385-3703-423d-8052-be7a7a061878",
                     "url": "/custom/service_instances/3955ad28-3f47-4f08-8eee-748f6e162d46/backups/4ffff7d4-55a8-4e57-9035-98ed11380991/restores/1a33a385-3703-423d-8052-be7a7a061878",
                     "created_at": "2016-10-03T20:52:38Z",
                     "updated_at": "2016-10-03T20:53:08Z"
                  },
                  "entity": {
                     "backup_id": "4ffff7d4-55a8-4e57-9035-98ed11380991",
                     "status": "SUCCEEDED"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So, the question is: **WHAT are all possible values in the "status" attributes on both cases, and WHEN do they happen?**

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for documentation purposes, I've got to know which are the available statuses:

Backup statuses:

- CREATE_IN_PROGRESS
- CREATE_SUCCEEDED
- CREATE_FAILED
- DELETE_IN_PROGRESS
- DELETE_SUCCEEDED
- DELETE_FAILED

Restore statuses:

- IN_PROGRESS
- SUCCEEDED
- FAILED

Moreover, it is not possible to trigger a **restore** when there is another **backup** *create* or *delete*, or another **restore** operation *in progress*.